# How can i insert a new article into joomla 2.5 database directly?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5 and want to insert 100 articles without using Joomla's article manager.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I wanted to add 100 articles as quickly as possible, I would take a backup of the `#__content` table in the database, open it in Notepad++, add all my articles in and re-upload the table.

If you do this, don't forget to assign each article a different ID.

Comment: What tables do i need to change?

Comment: I have already specified this in the answer. `#__content` . Make sure you keep a backup of the original table just incase you make a a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

This is incomplete. You also would need to add records to the assets table and to make sure that they are properly keyed to the content table and nesting within a category asset as well as the com_content asset. You can put all of the articles in the uncategorised category to handle that however.